# How to join several arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this arrays:
Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1) Array ( [0] => 1 )

I want join to one array and result equal :
Array ( [0] => 1 , [1] => 1 , [2] => 1 )

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you search PHP.net, Google, StackOverflow? If you look through the array_ functions on PHP.net, do you find something that will do what you want?

Your example is confusing because every array has a 1 in it, so we don't know if you want the same order or not, you're better to come up with a unique example. ie ['A'], ['B'], ['C'], and you want ['A', 'B', 'C'], not [1], [1], [1] and you want [1, 1, 1] because we can't tell if order is important.

Suggest you look at `array_merge()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

```
$arr1 = array(1);
$arr2 = array(2);
$arr3 = array(3);

$arr_all = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => int(1)
  [1] => int(2)
  [2] => int(3)
}
```